# "Warning database has been locked" warning with SQFlite and code stops. Why can I not query the table?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm having trouble querying a SQFlite db table in Flutter. I get the following warning several times:

```
I/chatty  (32047): uid=10160(com.example.SQFLite_test) 1.ui identical 18498 lines 2
I/flutter (32047): Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction 
object for database operations during a transaction
```

I get the warning when calling the `getClients()` method to get all clients from the `Client` table. The main issue though is that it seems to freeze the code as well. Even when I only try to select the top 100, it still gives me the warning and it freezes and doesn't progress.
My db class helping me to init and manage the database:

```
class LogServiceTwo {
  LogServiceTwo._();

  static final LogServiceTwo logRepo = LogServiceTwo._();

  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    var db = await openDb();
    // if (db == null) {
    //   _database = await initDB();
    //   return _database;
    // }

    var hasClientTableB = await hasClientTable(db);
    if (hasClientTableB) {
      _database = db;
      return _database;
    }

    // var backup = await restoreBackup(db);
    // if (backup != null) {
    //   _database = backup;
    //   return _database;
    // }

    await createClientTable(db);
    _database = db;
    return _database;
  }

  Future createClientTable(Database db) async {
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Client ("
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        "first_name TEXT,"
        "last_name TEXT,"
        "blocked BIT"
        ")");
  }

  Future<bool> hasClientTable(Database db) async {
    try {
      var table = await db.query("Client");
      return table != null;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> openDb() async {
    try {
      var path = await getPersistentDbPath();
      var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
      return db;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future initDB() async {
    var path = await getPersistentDbPath();
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {}, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Client ("
          "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "first_name TEXT,"
          "last_name TEXT,"
          "blocked BIT"
          ")");
    });
  }

  Future newClient(Client newClient) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.insert("Client", newClient.toMap());
    return res;
  }

  Future newClients(List<Client> clients) async {
    var clientMaps = clients.map((client) => client.toMap()).toList();
    final db = await database;
    clientMaps.forEach((clientMap) async {
      await db.insert("Client", clientMap);
    });
  }

  Future<Client> getClient(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.query("Client", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    return res.isNotEmpty ? Client.fromMap(res.first) : Null;
  }

  Future<List<Client>> getAllClients() async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.query("Client");
    List<Client> list = res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Client.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
    return list;
  }

  Future<List<Client>> getBlockedClients() async {
    final db = await logRepo.database;
    var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Client WHERE blocked=1");
    List<Client> list = res.isNotEmpty ? res.toList().map((c) => Client.fromMap(c)) : null;
    return list;
  }

  Future<List<String>> getTables() async {
    var db = await logRepo.database;
    var tableNames = (await db.query('sqlite_master', where: 'type = ?', whereArgs: ['table'])).map((row) => row['name'] as String).toList(growable: false);
    return tableNames;
  }

  Future<String> getPersistentDbPath() async {
    return await createPersistentDbDirecotry();
  }

  Future createPersistentDbDirecotry() async {
    var externalDirectoryPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var persistentDirectory = "$externalDirectoryPath/db_persistent";
    await createDirectory(persistentDirectory);
    return "$persistentDirectory/persistent.db";
  }

  Future createDirectory(String path) async {
    await (new Directory(path).create());
  }

  Future<bool> askForWritePermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      status = await Permission.storage.request();
      return status.isGranted;
    }
    return status.isGranted;
  }

  Future mockData() async {
    var clients = ClientMocker.createClients();
    await newClients(clients);
  }

  Future deleteAll() async {
    var db = await database;
    await db.rawDelete("DELETE FROM Client");
  }

  // Get all clients, throws warnings and stops proceeding in the code.
  Future getClients() async {
    try {
      var db = await database;
      return await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Client");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

My main class calling the database service for testing purposes:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // firstTest();
    // secondTest();
    thirdTest();
    testText = "";
    super.initState();
  }

  String testText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Text(testText),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future firstTest() async {
    testText = "";
    // var client = new Client(blocked: false, firstName: "Tobias", lastName: "Eliasson", id: null);
    // await LogRepository.logRepo.newClient(client);
    // await LogRepository.logRepo.newClient(client);
    // await LogRepository.logRepo.newClient(client);
    var clients = await LogRepository.logRepo.getAllClients();
    clients.forEach((c) {
      setState(() {
        testText += "\n${c.toMap()}";
      });
      print(c.toMap());
    });
    setState(() {
      testText += "Length of found clients: ${clients.length.toString()}";
    });

    var success = await LogRepository.logRepo.saveBackup();
    print(success);
  }

  Future secondTest() async {
    try {
      await LogRepository.logRepo.deleteAll();
      await LogRepository.logRepo.mockData();
      var a = DateTime.now();
      print("Saving backup $a");
      var backupSuccess = await LogRepository.logRepo.saveBackup();
      print("Backup success: $backupSuccess");
      var b = DateTime.now();
      print("Saved backup:${a.difference(b)}");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error!!!");
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future thirdTest() async {
    await LogServiceTwo.logRepo.database;
    await LogServiceTwo.logRepo.mockData();
    var clients = await LogServiceTwo.logRepo.getClients();
    print(clients.length);
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, I await all db operations and only use on db object to access it so there shouldn't be any weird parallell access going on. Maybe you find an error somewhere I'm missing though. In case you wonder why I create the database in external memory, is that the database needs to be persistent and saved when uninstalling the app or updating it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and learnt a lesson. In short, follow conventions and best practices when accessing a database. The problem was that I inserted one client at the time inside the method:

```
  Future newClients(List<Client> clients) async {
    var clientMaps = clients.map((client) => client.toMap()).toList();
    final db = await database;
    clientMaps.forEach((clientMap) async {
      await db.insert("Client", clientMap);
    });
  }
```

When inserting or doing many db operations at the same moment, use batch and commit instead like this:

```
 Future newClients(List<Client> clients) async {
    var clientMaps = clients.map((client) => client.toMap()).toList();
    final db = await database;
    var batch = db.batch();
    clientMaps.forEach((clientMap) async {
      batch.insert("Client", clientMap);
    });
    await batch.commit(noResult: true);
 }
```

With the batch and commit solution I could insert 90 000 clients on first try with no errors and could query them all after.